# writing to gz using fstream

Tags: c++, fstream, gzip

How can I write the output to a compressed file (gz, bz2, ...) using `fstream`? It seems that Boost library can do that, but I am looking for a non Boost solution. I saw example only for reading from a compressed file.

Comment: If you don't want to use Boost — implement the same yourself. As simple as that.

Comment: I believe he's asking how - he may not know about the libraries out there.

Comment: @Vlad Lazarenko: if I want to implement my own method by looking at the boost code, then I prefer to use Boost code!

Comment: @mahmood: So why don't you? :-D

Comment: @Vlad Lazarenko: Because I saw how to read from a compressed file using `gzstream.h`, but I didn't find an example how to use that for write

Comment: @mahmood, consider the possibility that this is an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/173950).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To write compressed data to a file, you would run your uncompressed data through a compression library such as [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/) (for DEFLATE, the compression algorithm used with .zip and .gz files) or [xz utils](http://tukaani.org/xz/) (for LZMA, the compression algorithm used with 7zip and .xz files), then write the result as usual using `ofstream` or `fwrite`.

Comment: Sure - zlib provides a step-by-step explanation of how to use it [here](http://www.zlib.net/zlib_how.html). Reading the library's documentation may also help.

Comment: @mahmood, [here](ftp://wuarchive.wustl.edu/mirrors/gnu/gzip/gzip-1.2.4.tar) is the canonical example.

Answer (score 2):

The two major pieces to implement are the [encoding/compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE#Stream_format) and [framing/encapsulation/file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip#File_format).

From wikipedia, the DEFLATE algorithm:

> Stream format
>
> A Deflate stream consists of a series of blocks. Each block is
>   preceded by a 3-bit header: 1 bit: Last-block-in-stream marker: 1:
>   this is the last block in the stream. 0: there are more blocks to
>   process after this one. 2 bits: Encoding method used for this block
>   type: 00: a stored/raw/literal section, between 0 and 65,535 bytes in
>   length. 01: a static Huffman compressed block, using a pre-agreed
>   Huffman tree. 10: a compressed block complete with the Huffman table
>   supplied. 11: reserved, don't use. Most blocks will end up being
>   encoded using method 10, the dynamic Huffman encoding, which produces
>   an optimised Huffman tree customised for each block of data
>   individually. Instructions to generate the necessary Huffman tree
>   immediately follow the block header. Compression is achieved through
>   two steps The matching and replacement of duplicate strings with
>   pointers. Replacing symbols with new, weighted symbols based on
>   frequency of use.

From wikipedia, the `gzip` file format:

> "gzip" is often also used to refer to the gzip file format, which is:
>   a 10-byte header, containing a magic number, a version number and a
>   timestamp optional extra headers, such as the original file name, a
>   body, containing a DEFLATE-compressed payload an 8-byte footer,
>   containing a CRC-32 checksum and the length of the original
>   uncompressed data